# Is there a push request feature available in gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, push, tortoisegit

[image: Gitflow workflow]

Using the gitflow model
Master, develop, and release branches are protected in Gitlab

A developer wants to push from local develop branch to remote develop branch using tortoisegit. He cannot do so because it is a protected branch. Could the push be reviewed and then merged to develop  branch by a Master user.

Or should the developer be allowed to push to the develop branch and let the master merge to release and master branches.

Comment: why can't you use merge-restests? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [axosoft Blog article: Pull Requests and Gitflow](https://blog.axosoft.com/pull-requests-gitflow/) there is a [Workflow graph](https://blog.axosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/FlowChart-701x1024.png):
[image: Workflow graph]

How to create a pull/merge request, see [gitlab Documentation: How to create a merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html)

Answer (score 2):

In gitflow you should push the feature / bugfix branches and create a [merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html) (AKA pull request in GitHub/Bitbucket) to develop.

So there is no need for pushing to develop from local.

Comment: As Vincent Driessen states, https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, feature exists on local repository of developer and I assume that the developer merges his feature branch to develop branch and pushes the develop branch to remote repository

Comment: @user3763570  yes, that's nice if you don't have a fancy git management tool, like Gitlab/Github/Bitbucket